# Can't bind to Active Directory with Perl

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap, netldap

I just installed Net::LDAP, but I can't authenticate to the AD server.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Net::LDAP;

my $ldap = "";
$ldap = Net::LDAP->new("serv01.noboundaries.dyndns.org");
my $mesg = "";
$mesg = $ldap->bind("CN=sansken,OU=NB_Users,DC=noboundaries,DC=dyndns,DC=org", password => "XXXXXXX");

die $mesg->error() if $mesg->code();
$mesg = $ldap->unbind;
```

The error I'm getting is:

> 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db0 at ./ldap.pl line 11,  line 751.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use DOMAIN\USER, instead of full DN .
You can use the upn too ( user@my.domain.net )

This code it's working for me:

```
my $ad_Obj = Net::LDAP->new('my.domain.net', port => 389) or die $!;
$ad_Obj->bind('MY\FooUser', password =>'MyReallySecurePassword')or die $!;

$Mesg = $ad_Obj->search(
    filter=>"(sAMAccountName=FooUser)",
    attrs => "['*']",
    base=>'DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net'
); 

foreach $ad_Object ($Mesg->entries) {
    print $ad_Object->dn() . "\n";
}

$ad_Obj->unbind;
$ad_Obj->disconnect;
```

Comment: I've edited the line attrs to add "", if dont works try filtering the query with cn instead of samaccountname

Comment: Still getting no output.  Is there anything in the Event Viewer on the Windows server that could show anything useful?

Comment: Are you sure that you are searching a user who exists? You can use wildcards in the query ( cn=f* ) . Also, you can add to the search scope => 'sub'. You can export a ldif from the user you are searching using ldifde? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/cc731033(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Exporting an LDIF works.  I tried your suggestions but I'm still getting no output.  I tried binding with a username that doesn't exist and it does not die... I think this is worth noting